# Maximal tori in U(2)

Tags: lie-groups

I'm attending a course about Lie Groups, and in an exercise I'm asked to "find the maximal abelian subgroup of $U(2)$". Certainly an abelian subgroup of $U(2)$ (and in fact of any $U(n)$ increasing the dimension of the matrices) is the 2-torus $S^1\times S^1$ made of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}e^{ia}&\\&e^{ib}\end{pmatrix}$, but how can I show that it is unique, or that it is the biggest one (I also find the question somewhy misleading: do I have to suppose the lattice of abelian subgroups in U(2) totally ordered by inclusion?)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the proper wording of the problem is to "find a maximal abelian subgroup of $U(2)$"; it is not unique, but all of them are conjugate. Your $S^1\times S^1$ is maximal.

Comment: Have you learned about the Lie algebra of a Lie group yet?  If you have a maximal abelian subgroup of U(2), what can you say about the Lie algebra of that subgroup?

Comment: @sweetjazz : I imagine that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak h$ of that subgroup will be a maximal subalgebra of the Lie algebra of the whole group... If I look for $T_\mathbb IU(n)$, I can see it is the space of anti-sym-conjugate matrices $\{X\in M_n(\mathbb C)\mid \bar{X}^t+X=\mathbb O\}$. So, now? Which is the Lie algebra of the 2-torus in $U(2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to see this is to put together the following two pieces:

1. Unitary matrices are (individually) diagonalizable.
2. A commuting set $S$ of diagnolizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable. IOW there is a single matrix $P$ such that all the matrices $PAP^{-1}$, with $A$ ranging over the set $S$, are diagonal.

Edit (item #1 clear, sketching an argument for item #2):

The question is equivalent to finding an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors of all the matrices in the set $S$. The proof goes by induction on $n$ = the size of the matrices. If you are only interested in $U(2)$, then you only need to worry about the case $n=2$, but the argument for general $U(n)$ works the same way, so we might as well.

If $n=1$, there is nothing to prove, because all the matrices are scalars. Thus the base case is clear.

Then to the general case. A unitary matrix with a single eigenvalue $\lambda$ is necessarily $\lambda I_n$, so if all the matrices in the set $S$ have only a single eigenvalue, then we are done. A more interesting case occurs, when at least one of the matrices in the set has two or more eigenvalues. Say that matrix $A\in S$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k$ (some of these may be repeated). In this case the ambient space $V=\mathbf{C}^n$ splits into an orthogonal sum of eigenspaces:
$$
V=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus \cdots \oplus V_k,
$$
where $V_i$ is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Note that because we assumed $k>1$, the dimensions of the spaces $V_i$ are all $<n$.

The key observation is that all the matrices in the set $S$ 'respect' this direct sum decomposition in the following set. Let's pick one of the subspaces, say $V_i$.
If $B$ is any matrix from the set $S$, and $v$ is a vector from the subspace $V_i$, then
$$
A(Bv)=(AB)v=(BA)v=B(Av)=B(\lambda_i v)=\lambda_i(Bv),
$$
because $A$ and $B$ commute, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. This calculation shows that $Bv$ is then another eigenvector of $A$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. IOW $Bv_i\in V_i$. Thus the restriction of the linear mappings of the set $S$ to the subspace $V_i$ form a commuting family of unitary matrices of size $\dim V_i$. By induction hypothesis, the space $V_i$ has an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors of all the matrices of the set $S$. The same argument works for all the subspaces $V_i$, so putting their bases together we get a basis of the desired form.

Comment: 1 is of course in the program of any linear algebra course i've ever heard of... for what concerns point 2, I knew that two unitary matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable, but I easily believe I can "induce" in some way.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: The induction is by the size of matrices, not by the number of matrices in the commuting set. I sketched an argument above.