# prove diagonalizablity using argument from representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\} \subseteq GL_d$ be a subgroup of commutating matrices then show this matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable (using some argument from representation theory)

Comment: What have you done so far? For example, do you know that two **diagonalizable** matrices are *simultaneously diagonalizable*  iff they commute? Are your matrices diagonalizable? Why? Why not?

Comment: Yes I noticed before that its enough to show diagonalizability of one matrix, but how to show that ? I was trying to show that like, setting up a homomorphism from an abelian group. Where abelian group is $\{1,2,...,n,*\}$ and operation is defined as, i*j is indices of $X_i*X_j$ and send each $i \to X_i$ is that correct ?

Comment: Well, I think I understand the claim when working over an algebraically closed field, say $\;\Bbb C\;$ , and using Schur's Lemma and stuff. This isn't given here, though.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on $\mathbb{C}$ and I don't see any problem in my construction ... but without that is there any way to show diagolazability using some representation th argument ?

Comment: Would the argument I give [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/81204/11619) be something that fits the bill? The basic idea is that as the matrices commute, they must stabilize each others' eigenspaces. The rest is by induction on $d$.

Comment: @Timbuc Even over an algebraically closed field, this will fail without further assumptions (namely that each matrix is diagonalizable).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'd have to check, but I think that over an alg. closed field one can prove that a begin a group then each matrix there is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Timbuc No, for example any upper triangular unipotent $2\times 2$ matrix will not be diagonalizable, regardless of the field (I actually had to think to find an example, but as far as I recall, being diagonalizable is a closed condition and since the invertible matrices are dense in the full set of matrices, all invertible ones being diagonalizable would imply that they would all be).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How can an unipotent matrix be part of a finite abelian group of matrices?

Comment: @Timbuc Ahh, I somehow missed the "finite" part.

Comment: @Timbuc Actually, in positive characteristic my example does work.