# Commuting Hermitian Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A$ and $B$ be commuting $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices. Prove that $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously unitary diagonalized. Also Prove that $AB = 0 = BA$, where $0$ is the zero matrix, implies that rank ($A + B$) = rank ($A$) + rank($B$).

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far. We know that $AB$ and $BA$ have a common eigenvector. The goal is to find a unitary matrix $S$ so that
$$D_A = S^* A S \quad \text{and} \quad D_B = S^* B S$$
where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are diagonal matrices.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: What facts about commuting matrices do you know that might apply here?

Comment: commuting matrices they have the same nonzero eigenvalues eigenvalues.

Comment: Did you cover the fact that they can be (simultaneously) upper triangularized with a unitary matrix?

Comment: Yep! That's the Schur Unitary Triangulation Theorem for commuting matrices. How can I use that result here?

Comment: The key is that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $Ax$. So you can do this *one eigenspace at the time* and do induction on the size of the matrices (=dimension of the eigenspace).

Comment: Note that if $UAU^*$ is upper triangular it must also be diagonal, since $UAU^*$ would be both upper-triangular **and Hermitian**.

Comment: A somewhat [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81192/11619). Omnomnomnom's suggestion may be better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Any ideas for how to prove that given that $AB = 0 = BA$ implies rank($A + B$) = rank($A$) + rank($B$).